# R all possible combinations

Tags: r, apply

I have fallowing data frame:

```
> my.df
          x         y
1 0.4597406 0.8439140
2 0.4579697 0.7461805
3 0.5593259 0.6646701
4 0.3607346 0.7792931
5 0.8377520 1.0445919
6 0.5597406 1.0445919
```

I want to create all possible combinations

```
> my.df
          x         y
1 0.4597406 0.8439140
2 0.4597406 0.7461805
3 0.4597406 0.6646701
4 0.4597406 0.7792931
5 0.4597406 1.0445919
6 0.4597406 1.0445919
7 0.4579697 0.8439140
8 0.4579697 0.7461805
9 0.4579697 0.6646701
... 
(Not all the combinations are showing here - This is to show the format that I would like to get the resulting data frame)
```

Using following functions didn't really give the exact combinations.

```
expand.grid(my.df)
```

Whats the best way to generate all possible combinations.

Comment: Is that the expected output i.e. the 9 rows?

Comment: set the columns to `factor` i guess that should work. but that gives arnd 36 rows (6*6)

Comment: I think you are looking for `combn` function.

Comment: The expand.grid gives 36 rows.  It is not clear based on what you meant by `all possible combinations`

Comment: @user2100721 could you please provide a example?

Comment: Without knowing what you expect, it is not easy to provide a solution.  How many combinations you expect?

Comment: @akrun each x should have a combination each y I believe it should be 36 i guess

Comment: If you expect 36 rows, then `expand.grid` should really do the job. If it doesn't, could you please elaborate why it is not satisfactory? Note that the combinations are not listed in the same order as in your example output, but you can reorder the rows of the resulting data frame afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe we can use `expand.grid` in the following way

```
expand.grid(x = my.df$x, y = my.df$y)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can just use `expand.grid`

```
res <- expand.grid(my.df)
dim(res)
#[1] 36  2
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(my.df)[,CJ(x,y)]
```

Answer (score 2):

A `Cross Join` is helpful in this situation. Since you didnt provide a reproducible example. I have create my own datset.

```
df=data.frame(x=runif(5), y=runif(5))
xx=data.frame(df$x)
yy=data.frame(df$y)
library(sqldf)
sqldf("SELECT * FROM xx CROSS JOIN yy")
```

Answer (score 2):

expand.grid() will give you all the possible combinations but not the unique combinations. If you need the latter you can use a function like this

```
unique_comb <- function(data){
   x.cur <- unique(data$x)
   y.cur <- unique(data$y)
   n.x <- length(x.cur)
   n.y <- length(y.cur)
   matrix.com <- matrix(0,ncol=2,nrow=n.x*n.y)
   ind <- 1
   for(i in 1:n.x){
       for(j in 1:n.y){
          matrix.com[ind,] <- c(x.cur[i],y.cur[j])
         ind <- ind+1
       }
   }
   return(matrix.com)
}
```

Or as JTT points that this can be done in one line with

```
expand.grid(unique(data$x),unique(data$y))
```

Comment: You can also give unique values to `expand.grid`. Something like this: `expand.grid(unique(my.df$x), unique(my.df$y))`.

Comment: @JTT yes, you are completely right! I tested it and t gives the same as my function (I knew there will be an easier way).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the merge function this way

```
dat <- cars[1:6,1:2]
dat
  speed dist
1     4    2
2     4   10
3     7    4
4     7   22
5     8   16
6     9   10

merge(dat$speed,dat$dist,by=NULL)
   x  y
1  4  2
2  4  2
3  7  2
4  7  2
5  8  2
6  9  2
7  4 10
8  4 10
9  7 10
10 7 10
11 8 10
12 9 10
13 4  4
14 4  4
15 7  4
16 7  4
17 8  4
18 9  4
19 4 22
20 4 22
21 7 22
22 7 22
23 8 22
24 9 22
25 4 16
26 4 16
27 7 16
28 7 16
29 8 16
30 9 16
31 4 10
32 4 10
33 7 10
34 7 10
35 8 10
36 9 10
```

Answer (score 0):

I know everyone's throwing `expand.grid()` at you, so here's another option...

```r
my.df <- structure(list(x = c(0.4597406, 0.4579697, 0.5593259, 0.3607346, 0.837752, 0.5597406), 
                        y = c(0.843914, 0.7461805, 0.6646701, 0.7792931, 1.0445919, 1.0445919)), 
                   .Names = c("x", "y"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")

my.df
#>           x         y
#> 1 0.4597406 0.8439140
#> 2 0.4579697 0.7461805
#> 3 0.5593259 0.6646701
#> 4 0.3607346 0.7792931
#> 5 0.8377520 1.0445919
#> 6 0.5597406 1.0445919
```

`tidyr` has a `complete()` function which "completes" your data combinations, which I believe is what you're after.

```
tidyr::complete(my.df, x, y)
#> # A tibble: 30 x 2
#>            x         y
#>        <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1  0.3607346 0.6646701
#> 2  0.3607346 0.7461805
#> 3  0.3607346 0.7792931
#> 4  0.3607346 0.8439140
#> 5  0.3607346 1.0445919
#> 6  0.4579697 0.6646701
#> 7  0.4579697 0.7461805
#> 8  0.4579697 0.7792931
#> 9  0.4579697 0.8439140
#> 10 0.4579697 1.0445919
#> # ... with 20 more rows
```

Note: this produces the *unique* combinations - your expected output rows 5 and 6 are identical.